# Microdisplacement and Adaptive Subdivision is not working

Tags: subdivision-surface, displacement, experimental-features

[image: Node Setup]
This is my Node Setup. I have a Subsurf Modifier that's set to adaptive with a dicing scale of 1 pixel and the displacement settings on "True". Despite all of that there's no displacement in both the rendered viewport and rendered image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a bump node there, I would rather substitute it with a "math -> multiply" node, with which you can change the displacement height.
In fact, what you are doing is taking a greyscale image, making a normal map out of it and plugging it into the displacement slot, which needs a greyscale image. But now you have wrong shades of grey because of that.

You also need correct render settings:
In the render tab, in the render pane, you need to change the feature set to "experimental" and in the material tab, in the settings pane, the displacement to "both". (And obviously you need your mesh to be unwrapped properly.)

Comment: Do I still need the normal map when using microdisplacement?

Comment: You dont need it, but you can use it on top of the displacement to give finer surface detail. 
Just leave the normal output of the cobblestone connected to the input of the BSDF node.

Just on a side node, you can connect an output to several different inputs, this way you only have to change one source if you need to. So, although its wrong, in your image you could have just connected the normal output of the cobblestone to the displacement input of the material output. This way you would have saved importing the height and converting it to a normal map. Just as a general rule of thumb.